# add an id to an element that doesn't have

Tags: entities

So, I want to create an onclick event with javascript for each option of a "select form" when clicked, but since drupal doesn't use HTML I can't modify it manually and put an id to each. This is the exact element I want to change (pic below). Can I do it modifying the php of the theme? I took a look at it but didn't make sense to me. (This is the Chrome inspect tool)[image]

Comment: You can try using the `onchange` event with `#ajax` property on that form field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `<option>` is not a valid target, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402268/9976763

You should bind the https://api.jquery.com/change/ event for the `<select>` instead and check if the given option is selected or not. For that, you do not need to put an ID on the option.

Also check https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api on how to write Javascript properly for Drupal.

Comment: Thanks, man. That's exactly what I was looking for.